# Office365 REST API Basic Authentication

Tags: office365, office365api

I was wondering if it's possible to perform RESP API calls to office365 using basic auth? I don't want to build a whole app using OAuth2, I just want to run some scripts on my environment. Does anything know if this is possible?

Comment: Are you looking to run your script on a single mailbox belonging to the signed in user or multiple mailboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. At launch the Outlook APIs would accept basic, but that was just to ease exploration and wasn't supported for production. I'm not sure if it is still allowed, the plan was to turn it off eventually. OAuth2 is required for productions use.

Comment: Is there anyway to get OAuth2 to work from just the command line?

Comment: Yes, you can. You'd still need to register an app to get a client ID. The Azure folks have a headless example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless